# Remover clase con Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo una div que al hacer clic se le añade una clase a otro div, al hacer clic fuera del que se le añade la clase quiero que se le quite la clase.
Tengo este código hasta el momento pero no funciona correctamente ya que agrega y elimina la clase al instante.

```
var sidebar = $('.sidebar-fixed-right');
$('.op-nvf8').on('click', function() {
   if(sidebar.hasClass('active')) {
        alert('load {{data}}');
   } else {
        sidebar.addClass('active');

        $(document).on("click",function(e) {
            if (!sidebar.is(e.target) && sidebar.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
                sidebar.removeClass('active');
            }
        });
   }
});
```

Comment: porque no pones el código completo, con todo y html para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: y si sacas el evento click asignado al documento por fuera del else